# Кэширование картинок требует обновления по F5

Tags: html, кэширование

Пользователь меняет картинки на баннере через FTP, но браузеры его не меняют, пока не нажать F5
Но ведь не все юзеры будут это делать!

Прописал

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Но не помогает (кажется, только в Chrome срабатывает).
Картинки из баннерокрутилки, пример можно видеть [тут](http://xn--24-dlcmfmh3d.xn--p1ai).

Какой ещё выход из этого положения есть?
Или может скрипт какой навесить на баннерокрутилку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тег **meta** вам не поможет. Добавляйте случайный текст в качестве **query_string** для всех картинок.

```
<img src='/path-to-image/image.png?v=tAbd4l' />
```

Функция на javascript для генерации строки из 5 случайных символов:

```
function makeid() {
    var text = "",
        possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789",
        p_length = possible.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * p_length));
    return text;
}
```

**[Пример использования](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/5Ya9x/4/)**

**html**

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff944e/000000.png" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/4e94ff/000000.png" />
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider'),
    slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider img'),
    slides_total = slides.length;

for (var i = 0; i < slides_total; ++i) {
    slides[i].src += '?v=' + makeid();
}
```

**Дополнение**

Чтобы изображение точно грузилось после javascript **[делаем так](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/5Ya9x/5/)**.
Суть: сначала грузим прозрачный gif 1x1 пикселей, а потом скриптом заменяем его настоящей картинкой.

**html**

```
<!--
R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
Прозрачный gif 1x1 пикселей
-->
<div class="slider">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,код_из_комментария_выше"
         data-src="http://placehold.it/100/ff944e/000000.png" />
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,код_из_комментария_выше"
         data-src="http://placehold.it/100/4e94ff/000000.png" />
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider'),
    slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider img'),
    slides_total = slides.length;

for (var i = 0; i < slides_total; ++i) {
    var img = slides[i];
    slides[i].src = img.getAttribute('data-src') + '?v=' + makeid();
}
```

Comment: @VenZell спасибо. Ответ принял.  
Но я по старой привычке решил через PHP:  
`<img src="pictures.jpg?=<?php echo rand(0, 10); ?>" />`  
Наверное PHP при большой посещаемости проекта в таком варианте это плохо?

Comment: @I_CaR, вы забыли указать, на чем у вас сайт, поэтому я привел в качестве примера решения код на javascript.

Comment: Всегда ли однозначно раньше исполнится JS, прежде, чем станут загружаться картинки, или возможен случай, что загрузятся старые картинки, потом DOM ready, и лишь потом картинки заменятся на исправленные?

Comment: Это можно обойти. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Ваш веб сервер nginx настроен так, что отдаёт картинки [с заголовками](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjy6kty5lyrruu8/Screenshot%202014-02-06%2012.04.30.png)

```
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Sat, 08 Mar 2014 07:34:48 GMT
```

Чтобы баннеры не сохранялись в кэше браузера, надо либо приписывать к запросу картинки случайный GET аргумент, как посоветовал [[@VenZell](/users/13336/venzell)](/users/13336/venzell), либо настроить nginx, чтобы отдавал картинки из папки баннеров с коротким временем кэширования, напр. 5 минут – этого достаточно, чтобы в рамках одного визита на сайт баннеры запросились лишь один раз, и в то же время, не более 5 минут прошло, прежде, чем все увидят новый загруженный баннер:

```
location /js/banner-slider {
    expires    5m;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант запретить кэширование изображений, выдавая определенные заголовки к ним через веб-сервер.

Например:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html#100_Prevent_Files_cached

(в вашем случае регулярное выражение должно быть другим)